# VBA - Plot scatter of specific array column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array with two columns and I would like to plot it in a scatter. I am trying to use the following but it says subscript out of range.

```
With myChartObject.Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(a + 1).Name = testID
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(a + 1).XValues = arr()(0)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(a + 1).Values = arr()(1)
End With
```

I want all the values in the first column (0) to be the X axis and the ones in the second column (1) to be the Y axis values.

Thanks